# How to set the Ripple effect

Tags: android, android-layout, ripple

I am working on an app which has a minSdkVersion = 16, and I need to use the ripple effect in Lollipop and above and some other effect on lower version.
Is there any way to do this using XML?

Comment: *Ripple* effect for which purpose ? on which widget you want to use ? Please give more details.

Comment: @Ajay see [this](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need to design any other layout just for specific version just Use this library for ripple effect

https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect

compile line for this library

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3'
```

}

Comment: Can i use com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.3 library in api 14 ?

Comment: Ya you can use https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect both library has same kind of behaviour

Comment: Thanx Bro I Will Try

Comment: it works but it crash on 6.0 
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Underflow in restore - more restores than saves

Answer (score 1):

You can use Material Design on pre lollipop Devices.
You need to add in your gradle this :

> compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'

Read the reference on Google blog [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.gr/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create different XML files for pre-Lollipop and Lollipop or higher
[image]